How to effficiently calculate balance from long history of transactions in PostgreSQL?
I am currently working on a wallet system that allows transfers of money between users. I came up with the following structure, intending for the system to be robust, scalable, and capable of handling various types of financial transactions with proper tracking and integrity.
I am using PostgreSQL 16 and this is my schema:
CREATE TABLE users (
    id UUID PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT gen_random_uuid(),
    name VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    updated_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);

CREATE TABLE wallets (
    id UUID PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT gen_random_uuid(),
    user_id UUID REFERENCES users(id),
    balance NUMERIC(15, 2) DEFAULT 0.00,
    currency VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
    created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    updated_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);

CREATE TABLE transactions (
    id UUID PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT gen_random_uuid(),
    wallet_id UUID REFERENCES wallets(id),
    transaction_type VARCHAR NOT NULL CHECK (transaction_type IN ('credit', 'debit', 'transfer', 'refund', 'void')),
    amount NUMERIC(15, 2) NOT NULL,
    currency VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
    status VARCHAR NOT NULL CHECK (status IN ('pending', 'completed', 'voided', 'refunded')),
    reference_id UUID REFERENCES transactions(id),
    created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    updated_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);

CREATE TABLE transfers (
    id UUID PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT gen_random_uuid(),
    sender_wallet_id UUID REFERENCES wallets(id),
    receiver_wallet_id UUID REFERENCES wallets(id),
    transaction_id UUID REFERENCES transactions(id),
    amount NUMERIC(15, 2) NOT NULL,
    currency VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
    status VARCHAR NOT NULL CHECK (status IN ('pending', 'completed', 'voided', 'refunded')),
    created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    updated_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);

In order to know the balance of a wallet, my application can do the following query:
SELECT 
    COALESCE(SUM(
        CASE 
            WHEN transaction_type = 'credit' THEN amount 
            WHEN transaction_type = 'debit' THEN -amount 
            WHEN transaction_type = 'transfer' AND wallet_id = '$walletid' THEN -amount 
            WHEN transaction_type = 'transfer' AND wallet_id != '$walletid' THEN amount 
            ELSE 0 
        END
    ), 0) AS balance
FROM transactions
WHERE wallet_id = '$walletid' AND status = 'completed';

As wallets grow older, how to speed up the balance query? The more active a wallet is, the slower balance calculation is going to be. It always needs to calculate every single credit/debit since the beginning of time. I am afraid this design will not scale to many transactions.

Why don't you just keep the current balance?  This way is obviously much slower, so what is the benefit?

new transactions should not exist before wallets.updated_at (and those transaction should never change...!). So you only need to add the not yet completed transactions after that datetime.

Don't. Keep the balance up to date on the fly. You already have wallets.balance to store it in.
You have three options.
You could do it in application code. This is acceptable if your application is the only way to change data in the database, such as in a framework like Ruby On Rails. If you have multiple code bases which can alter data, do not use this approach.
You could write a periodic maintenance process which looks for new transactions since the last time the wallet balance was updated, sums them, and adds them. I don't recommend this approach. It's complicated, it means a delay between transactions and balance updates, and it could run into trouble if something else updates wallets.updated_at.
You could use a trigger. This guarantees it will always happen. Create insert, update, and delete triggers on transactions to update wallets.balance appropriately. Since it's very important to keep the balances correct, this is the approach I would recommend.
You can also periodically run a maintenance process to verify wallet balances by summing up all transactions.

Notes:

Your balance query does not take into account that the transactions and wallets might have different currencies.
Currencies should be treated as their own thing with their own table. This is useful for referential integrity, as a place to store information about a currency (name, symbol, etc), and to use as a foreign key for an exchange_rate table.

